# Discord.js/javascript issue with a error. if (command ==='clear'). ReferenceError: command not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Every time an error pops up saying if(command==='clear') referencerError: command is not defined, although bot is going online but not responding to any instruction in discord bot. Thanks for help, in advance!
i tried deleting if(command==='clear') whole section but then it showed the same error in the next play command which is one of the main command for music bot.
i have also linked the youtube video which i was using as a reference for this code and i tried to do exactly what he said to do to code my discord bot.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wJJDM7jUsk&list=RDCMUC08G-UJT58SbkdmcOYyOQVw&index=2

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client =  new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '!';

const fs = require('fs');
 
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
 
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


client.once('ready',() =>{
    console.log('Tihadi.io is online!');

} );
client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember => {
    let welcomeRole = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name ==='member');
    guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('783308287571132417').send(`Welcome <@$<{guildMember.user.id}> malik, To our server!`)
});



 


client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const commands = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (command === 'clear') {
        client.commands.get('clear').execute(message ,args);
    }else if (command==='play') {
        client.commands.get('play').execute(message ,args);
    }else if (command==='leave') {
        client.command.get('leave').execute(messsage ,args);
    }

    
});
 
 



client.login('token');
```

Comment: It's `commands` (`const commands = ...`) not `command`

Answer (score 0):

In your code you define `commands` as a variable, but then you try and check `command` against some strings. You are also missing an `s` on one of your `client.commands.get()`.

To fix this error you can do:

```js
if (commands == 'clear') {
    client.commands.get('clear').execute(message ,args);
}else if (commands == 'play') {
    client.commands.get('play').execute(message ,args);
}else if (commands == 'leave') {
    client.commands.get('leave').execute(messsage ,args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help you!

```js
client.commands = new Collection()

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for(const file of commandFiles){
 const commands = require(`./commands/${file}`)
 client.commands.set(commands.name, commands)
}
```